# filtering using dropdown list primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

jsf 2.0 primefaces 5.1 glassfish 4

i am using filtering via a dropdown list, when i click an item on the list the datatable gets filtered but the value in the dropdown list still shows "select one" instead of the selected value

```
<p:column headerText="Region" filterBy="#{wan.Region}"
            filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <f:facet name="filter">
          <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('table').filter()">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"
                              noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{wandbBean.regions}" />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{wan.Region}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs because you did not set `value="#{wan.Region}"`  into `<p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('table').filter()">`.

Therefore, the exactly code should be

```
<p:column headerText="Region" filterBy="#{wan.Region}"
            filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <f:facet name="filter">
          <p:selectOneMenu value="#{wan.Region}" onchange="PF('table').filter()">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"
                              noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{wandbBean.regions}" />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{wan.Region}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: This answer does not work and you'll get an error like this:   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: .... YOUR_PAGE_PATH_AND_NAME value="#{wan.Region}": Target Unreachable, identifier [wan] resolved to null. Please look at my answer bellow.

Comment: @ahmad: it might not work for your unspecified newer version... please ALWAYS specify currently used versions if you answer an old question

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as follows:

```
<p:column headerText="Region" filterBy="#{wan.Region}"
            filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <f:facet name="filter">
          <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('table').filter()">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"
                              noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{wandbBean.regions}" 
                               itemValue="#{wan.Region.VALUE}"
                               itemLabel="#{wan.Region.LABEL}" />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{wan.Region}" />
    </p:column>
```

The VALUE is whatever you want to pass to the controller and the LABEL is whatever you want to show in your drop-down.
This solution works on PrimeFace version 8.0 but I did not check it with older versions.